# SQL How to capture/check a particular text from standard column to populate value for calculated column

Tags: sql-server, substring, case, calculated-columns, charindex

In SQL Server 2016, I have a table with a varchar column (title) that has some of the values as below

```
title
ProALPHA - S - HTML Custom Table implementation (E001445)
IKA CP Implementation (Aus) (E001534-0001)
Test Engagment Integration: (E001637-0003) Non-billable
Customer requests customization for Analytics and Java Migration - E000797
Create list with customers renewing in H2 2020
```

I want to populate the value for the calculated (derived) column based on the above title column in such a way that,

Find If the title column contains text E00 then only the derived column will have the E00 value else NULL

Example,

[image: Expected Output]

Thanks

Comment: Is the value you want ***always*** suffixed by a right parenthesis (`)`) or terminates the string? If not, what denotes it has ended?

Comment: @Larnu there is no such standard pattern of string, But for now, there are 2 patterns and this is how it will be 

1. E00... text will always close with right parenthesis ( ) )
2. If E00... the text does not contain any closing right parenthesis ( ) ) then nothing will be in the end, that text itself will be the last thing of the complete string (Refer- Example 5th Row)

Comment: So "Yes, the value I want is always suffixed by a right parenthesis (`)`) or terminates the string."*?

Comment: Yes, like I said there are 2 patterns, But what you are saying is the 1st pattern. The value that I want is always suffixed with the right parenthesis ( ) )

Comment: @VikasJ Not according to your desired results - otherwise you would not have included E000797.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming my question about that the value always suffixes the string, or the value you want is always suffixed by a right parenthesis, then you can do the following with some `CHARINDEX`s and `SUBSTRING`:

```sql
USE Sandbox;
GO

SELECT V.Title,
       SUBSTRING(V.Title,E.CI,RP.CI - E.CI) AS YourColumn
FROM (VALUES('ProALPHA - S - HTML Custom Table implementation (E001445)'),
            ('IKA CP Implementation (Aus) (E001534-0001)'),
            ('Test Engagment Integration: (E001637-0003) Non-billable'),
            ('Customer requests customization for Analytics and Java Migration - E000797'),
            ('Create list with customers renewing in H2 2020'))V(Title)
      CROSS APPLY (VALUES(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('E00',V.Title),0)))E(CI)
      CROSS APPLY (VALUES(ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(')',V.Title,E.CI),0),LEN(V.Title)+1)))RP(CI);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e2fac3d1d40d9898127a0d8a6b640a90)

Comment: Thanks, @Larnu but can I populate the value of the derived column at runtime. Basically while creating table syntax. once the standard column title gets its value based on that derived column should get values as E00.. or NULL.

Comment: What do you mean "At run time" @VikasJ ? The value of column, `YourColumn`, *is* calculated at run time; the time you run the `SELECT`.

Comment: I mean I want to specify a Computed column while creating a table that will get a value of E00 or NULL based on the value of the standard title column.

Comment: You'll need to take the expressions in the above and nest them then, @VikasJ .

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use a combination of `Charindex` and `Substring`. Note in the following `100` should just be the declared length of the column - charindex will always stop at the end of the string.

This doesn't require ending parenthesis, it looks for the last digit.

```
with t as (
    select * from (values 
        ('ProALPHA - S - HTML Custom Table implementation (E001445)'                                    ),
        ('IKA CP Implementation (Aus) (E001534-0001)'                                                                   ),
        ('Test Engagment Integration: (E001637-0003) Non-billable'                                      ),
        ('Customer requests customization for Analytics and Java Migration - E000797'   ),
        ('Create list with customers renewing in H2 2020'                                                           )
    )t(title)
)
select title, 
   Iif(title like '%E00%',Reverse(Substring(part,patindex('%[0-9]%',part),100)),null)
from t
cross apply (values( Reverse(Substring(t.title, CharIndex('E00',t.title), 100 )) ))x(part)
```

[Example Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=ae3e202cd979903668740d469a0a626c)

**Update**

You *could* implement the above as a *computed column* with the help of a *function* to replace the use of *apply*.

This might be fine for your use-case, although I'd recommend using a *view* if at all possible.

```
create function dbo.E00_Part(@title varchar(100))
returns varchar(100)
as
begin
    return (select Reverse(Substring(@title, CharIndex('E00',@title), 100 )))
end

create table T (title varchar(100), 
  Computed as Iif(title like '%E00%',
    Reverse(Substring(dbo.E00_Part(title),patindex('%[0-9]%',dbo.E00_Part(title)),100)),null))
```

[See demo fiddle 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=7b9334e7912dac3d383cdfe90c41c081)

Comment: Thanks, @Stu but can I populate the value of the derived column at runtime. Basically while creating table syntax. once the standard column title gets its value based on that derived column should get values as E00.. or NULL.

Comment: @VikasJ now you're asking a different question about a *computed column* - at least this wasn't clear from your question, a derived column applies to any value computed from an existing column.

Comment: Apologies, If my question wasn't clear. But yes, I want to specify a Computed column while creating a table that will get a value of E00 or NULL based on the value of the standard title column.

Comment: @VikasJ I have suggested an update above

Comment: Thank you so much @Stu, But when I added 2 more types of title I couldn't get the expected output in the Computed column. Please check the last 2 rows results.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=65fc48d41577de8bd5c2b8057a38faa7

Comment: @VikasJ While I can amend it to cope with the first new row, your new second row breaks the rules you've already established, ie, the last row now has no closing brace and the number is not at the end of the string, so is neither of the "two patterns" you have documented.

Comment: agreed It's just that I got this new scenario of the last row a few mins back from the Client, wherein the number could be at the beginning or end with or without braces.
And what changes to make to make the first new row to give expected result? Because I tried to make changes in Reg expression of patindex %[0-9]% but that didn't worked well.

Comment: So if you now replace the [0-9] with a closing brace it will work for your first new row, however the approach needs to be different given your new criteria. Unfortunately this is a moved goalpost.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239486/discussion-between-vikas-j-and-stu).